# C++ compitator for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and want to install C++ free compilator what shall I write in terminal?

Comment: can you please describe what you did to solve your problem and which pages you found via websearch. also elaborate on why those did not solve your problem.

Comment: When asking how to install C++ compilator in Ubuntu 16.04 I got the answer that it is valid only for Ubuntu 15 so I got confused if I can download it on my version?

Comment: we are talking about g++, aren't we? try install it using apt: `sudo apt install g++`

Comment: I have found out that too in websearch but it also says that it is for Ubuntu 15 are you sure I can use sudo apt install g++ in my version?

Comment: under normal circumstances (means: you did not modify anything in the directory /etc/apt/) you can trust the package management to install packages that fit your system.

Comment: I don´t know I got help with installing Linux Ubuntu on my computer so I have´nt modifiey anything. I do not know if they did that! I have´nt programmed anything since 2001 and now I am a retired old laydy aged 68. My old computer is broken and I want to get started again with a new laptop. Exercising my brain. I have some difficulties with new things after 5 times surgery in my brain.

Comment: ok, let me write a complete answer and then you will most probably be ready to go with everything you need to start coding.

Answer (score 0):

The most important stuff will get installed as a dependency for the package `build-essential`. To install it, open a terminal (dash -> terminal) and run the following command:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

The c++ compiler is called `g++` and you should find plenty of howto's and tutorials on the internet.
One of my favorite sources for those stuff is https://learnxinyminutes.com/ where you can find multiple short tutorials to get you started in nearly every programming language.

Comment: https://learnxinyminutes.com/ 's SSL certificate is not valid anymore since today. This might hopefully be solved soon.

Comment: Thank you so much Phillip. Now I can trust that line I found it too but I was insecure. If anyting failiures I will look back on your answer and think all will be fine! Thank´s again Sonja